# If there is no attachment file is present at path mail should not send

Tags: vba, excel

If there is no attachment file is present at path mail should not send.

Is there any possibility that mail should not be send if there is no attachment?

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
strbody = " Hello"
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "test@gmail.com"
    .cc = "test1@gmail.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "TRANSACTING : " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    'You can add an attachment like this
    .Attachments.Add ("E:\Auto Reports\test.xlsb")
    .send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all using `On Error Resume Next` in the way you did just mute any errors. But the errors still occur they just don't show. Using `On Error Resume Next` is a very bad practice and you should avoid that unless you really know why you need to do it.

Instead you should always implement a proper error handling like below.
Now the error is shown if adding an attachment to the email fails and the email is not sent.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendMyEMail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    strbody = " Hello"

    On Error GoTo MAIL_ERROR 'jump to the error handler if an error occurs
        With OutMail
            .to = "test@gmail.com"
            .cc = "test1@gmail.com"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "TRANSACTING : " & Format(Date, "DD-MMM-YYYY")
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            'You can add an attachment like this
            .Attachments.Add ("C:\Auto Reports\test.xlsb")
            .send   'or use .Display
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop error handling here (no jumps to the error handler anymore.

    'The following 2 lines can be omitted because it is done automatically on exit sub
    'So these are completely unnecessary.
      'Set OutMail = Nothing 
      'Set OutApp = Nothing

    Exit Sub 'we need this to not to run into error handler if everything was ok

MAIL_ERROR: 'Show error message
    MsgBox "An error occured during sending the email. The email was not sent: " & vbNewLine & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```

---

#### Send multiple different e-mails

To send multiple different e-mails you need to make your procedure a more universal function receiving some parameters.

```
Public Function SendMyEMail(MailTo As String, MailCC As String, MailSubject As String, MailFileName As String)
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    strbody = " Hello"

    On Error GoTo MAIL_ERROR 'jump to the error handler if an error occurs
        With OutMail
            .To = MailTo
            .CC = MailCC
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = MailSubject
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            'You can add an attachment like this
            .Attachments.Add MailFileName
            .send   'or use .Display
        End With
    On Error GoTo 0 'stop error handling here (no jumps to the error handler anymore.

    'The following 2 lines can be omitted because it is done automatically on exit sub
    'So these are completely unnecessary.
      'Set OutMail = Nothing
      'Set OutApp = Nothing

    Exit Function 'we need this to not to run into error handler if everything was ok

MAIL_ERROR:     'Show error message
    MsgBox "An error occured during sending the email. The email was not sent: " & vbNewLine & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Function
```

And a procedure `SendMultipleEmails` looping through a worksheet and run `SendMyEMail` for every row.

```
Public Sub SendMultipleEmails()
    Dim wsMail As Worksheet
    Set wsMail = Worksheets("MyMailSheet")

    Dim iRow As Long, lRow As Long
    lRow = wsMail.Cells(wsMail.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column A

    For iRow = 1 To lRow 'run from first to last used row
        SendMyEMail wsMail.Cells(i, "A"), wsMail.Cells(i, "B"), wsMail.Cells(i, "C"), wsMail.Cells(i, "D")
        'SendMyEMail for every row in that sheet where MailTo is in column A, MailCC is in column B, …
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: i am getting error Compile error:

Member already exists in object module from which this object module derives

Comment: Ehm my bad, just change the name of the sub to something else. It seems to be that `SendMail` is a reserved name already existing. I updated my answer and changed it to `SendMyEMail`.

Comment: Thank you Boss....!!!! it works very properly...... and do we have option that i can give the list of recipient , CC , subject line & attachment file name in excel sheet cell instead of creating multiple macro

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the file exists before attempting to draft the email.

```
Sub SendEmail()

    'Exit if file does not exist
    If Len(Dir("E:\Auto Reports\test.xlsb", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Proceed
    Dim OutApp As Object

    'rest of code
End Sub
```

Comment: I would say the best way is to implement a proper error handling and not to send the email if an error occurs. Just checking if a file exists on the file system can still run into errors during adding it as an attachment (e.g. cannot read the file).

Comment: I agree, proper error handling should always be implemented especially when dealing with objects. But since you can check if the file exists, why let it throw an error?

Comment: As I said even if there is a file existing this doesn't mean that he can read it and attach it. Then in his code above it will still send an email without attachment. So this doesn't really solve his issue unless he implements an error handling.

Comment: At the beginning of the procedure. It will check if the file exists and if not, it will exit. If the file exists, it will continue and issue the email.